# CONDAHTTPERROR and SSLERROR in Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, http-error

#### Problem:

While installing or creating an environment, I get same type of error. I have uninstalled and installed back anaconda 7-8 times, still unable to solve this issue.

#### Script:

```
(base) C:\Users\Ritesh>conda create --name tensorflow python=3.6
Solving environment: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/msys2/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))
```

Please help me in the best possible way.

Comment: Did you google the error "Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available." you're seeing? There's a thread about it here. https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6064

Comment: I have gone through this and also googled it multiple times but it's not working.

Comment: Even the last comment here? https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6064#issuecomment-463219171

Comment: Thank you so much..this helped me a lot

Comment: Glad I could help. I posted the comment as an answer; feel free to accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling the error yields [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6064).

In particular, the [last comment](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6064#issuecomment-463219171) should help you resolve things by updating to a newer version of Python with a patch for this problem. Copying it here to avoid a link-only answer:

> The latest builds of Python have a new patch that should help fix this issue [...].
>
> The fixed builds of python are:
>
> - 2.7.15 build 7
> - 3.6.8 build 1
> - 3.7.2 build 2
>
> After updating to these builds, you should be able to remove any workaround that you added to make conda work. As one further workaround to get conda to install an updated python, you can download it manually from https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64/ and tell conda to install the file directly. For example, with python 3.7:
>
> > `conda install c:\Users\you\Downloads\python-3.7.2-h8c8aaf0_2.tar.bz2`
>
> This does not install dependencies for you, so definitely do not try to switch python versions this way (i.e. if you already have 3.7.x, download the 3.7.2 package, not 3.6.8 or 2.7.15).

Comment: I'm seeing this issue with 2.7.16 build 0 (installed from miniconda3). Also get windows runtime error R6034.